# CSS svg file animation and transform not working

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

I'm trying to do a transform animation with a SVG, but the animation or transform isn't working at all. I tried to research it, but it didn't help. Is there any solution for that?
The code below is just SVG file. I downloaded it from google.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
<svg className="katana" width={35} height={35} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <g id="flat">
    <path
      d="M43,43H38.952a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-2.273-1.926h0a4.816,4.816,0,0,0-3.642-3.962,4.728,4.728,0,0,0-5.695,3.834l-.021.128A2.3,2.3,0,0,1,25.048,43H21a6,6,0,0,0-6,6h5v3h8V49h8v3h8V49h5A6,6,0,0,0,43,43Z"
      fill="#746250"
    />
    <path
      d="M28,33H24V16a2,2,0,0,1,2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2Z"
      fill="#8d7761"
    />
    <path
      d="M40,34H36V16a2,2,0,0,1,2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2Z"
      fill="#8d7761"
    />
    <path
      d="M59,20H10.653a8.819,8.819,0,0,1-6.236-2.583L3,16H59a2,2,0,0,1,2,2h0A2,2,0,0,1,59,20Z"
      fill="#d9d9d9"
    />
    <path d="M59,16H46v4H59a2,2,0,0,0,0-4Z" fill="#b6534f" />
    <path
      d="M55,32H12a2,2,0,0,1-2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2-2H55Z"
      fill="#e06661"
    />
    <rect x="47" y="28" width="4" height="4" fill="#dededc" />
    <rect x="39" y="28" width="4" height="4" fill="#dededc" />
    <rect
      x="44"
      y="12"
      width="4"
      height="12"
      rx="2"
      ry="2"
      fill="#daa857"
    />
    <rect
      x="56.707"
      y="17"
      width="2"
      height="2"
      transform="translate(4.174 46.077) rotate(-45)"
      fill="#dededc"
    />
    <rect
      x="50.707"
      y="17"
      width="2"
      height="2"
      transform="translate(2.417 41.834) rotate(-45)"
      fill="#dededc"
    />
    <rect
      x="53.707"
      y="17"
      width="2"
      height="2"
      transform="translate(3.295 43.956) rotate(-45)"
      fill="#dededc"
    />
    <path
      d="M26,30h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2V52a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H24a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V32A2,2,0,0,1,26,30Z"
      fill="#9a826a"
    />
    <path
      d="M40,52H36V32a2,2,0,0,1,2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2Z"
      fill="#9a826a"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

#flat

```
#flat:hover {
    animation-name: sumarai;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; }

@keyframes samurai {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {    
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    } }
```

Comment: There's a typo in your css animation name: should be  **"samurai"** not "sumarai".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
svg:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

svg{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg className="katana" width={35} height={35} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <g id="flat">
    <path
      d="M43,43H38.952a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-2.273-1.926h0a4.816,4.816,0,0,0-3.642-3.962,4.728,4.728,0,0,0-5.695,3.834l-.021.128A2.3,2.3,0,0,1,25.048,43H21a6,6,0,0,0-6,6h5v3h8V49h8v3h8V49h5A6,6,0,0,0,43,43Z"
      fill="#746250"
    />
    <path
      d="M28,33H24V16a2,2,0,0,1,2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2Z"
      fill="#8d7761"
    />
    <path
      d="M40,34H36V16a2,2,0,0,1,2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2Z"
      fill="#8d7761"
    />
    <path
      d="M59,20H10.653a8.819,8.819,0,0,1-6.236-2.583L3,16H59a2,2,0,0,1,2,2h0A2,2,0,0,1,59,20Z"
      fill="#d9d9d9"
    />
    <path d="M59,16H46v4H59a2,2,0,0,0,0-4Z" fill="#b6534f" />
    <path
      d="M55,32H12a2,2,0,0,1-2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2-2H55Z"
      fill="#e06661"
    />
    <rect x="47" y="28" width="4" height="4" fill="#dededc" />
    <rect x="39" y="28" width="4" height="4" fill="#dededc" />
    <rect
      x="44"
      y="12"
      width="4"
      height="12"
      rx="2"
      ry="2"
      fill="#daa857"
    />
    <rect
      x="56.707"
      y="17"
      width="2"
      height="2"
      transform="translate(4.174 46.077) rotate(-45)"
      fill="#dededc"
    />
    <rect
      x="50.707"
      y="17"
      width="2"
      height="2"
      transform="translate(2.417 41.834) rotate(-45)"
      fill="#dededc"
    />
    <rect
      x="53.707"
      y="17"
      width="2"
      height="2"
      transform="translate(3.295 43.956) rotate(-45)"
      fill="#dededc"
    />
    <path
      d="M26,30h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2V52a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H24a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V32A2,2,0,0,1,26,30Z"
      fill="#9a826a"
    />
    <path
      d="M40,52H36V32a2,2,0,0,1,2-2h0a2,2,0,0,1,2,2Z"
      fill="#9a826a"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```